# h:SelectOneMenu valueChangeListenr does not invoke

Tags: ajax, jsf, jboss, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I need to intercept valueChange event on h:SelectOneMenu element, but it does not work. What I could miss?

I tried both this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MainPage.<value_name>}"
                         valueChangeListener="#{MainPage.<method_name>}">
...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MainPage.<value_name>}">
...
    <f:ajax render="@form" event="change" listener="#{MainPage.<method_name>}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

these do not want to work.
Here is my method:

```
public void <method_name>(ValueChangeEvent e){
    ...
    System.out.println(">>>Changed<<<");
}
```

as a result, nothing happened, and there are no any errors in logs.
I'm using NetBeans 7.3 with jboss AS 7.1.

Comment: Please check that you don't have an validation error place <p:message to check that if error exits or not if validation error is present put immediate=true that should work

Comment: Thanks, BholaVishwakarma, <h:message/> tag helped me to deal with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<h:message/>` tag helped me to deal with my problem. The problem was in types and in lack of custom converters.

Answer (score 0):

For the first way, try to add the essential attribute :

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="submit()" ... >
```

For the second way, the class of the paramter event in the method should be : `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

Also, make sure your controller-bean is `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: It was '@SessionScoped', I changed to '@ViewScoped', but it didn't help. Swaping ValueChangeEvent for AjaxBehaviorEvent led to nothing too.

Comment: Did you add the attribute onchange ?

Comment: Yes. Problem was in another.